# woocommerce advanced templating

Tags: templates, woocommerce

i´m developing a theme and for some reason i need to move the default position for breadcrubms (also for many other things) over woocommerce themes. Then i realised to do something like this on my functions.php:

```
function woocommerce_remove_breadcrumb(){
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 20);
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_remove_breadcrumb');

function woocommerce_custom_breadcrumb(){
    woocommerce_breadcrumb();
    }
add_action( 'woo_custom_breadcrumb', 'woocommerce_custom_breadcrumb' );
```

And then on any template file, output the breadcrumb just with:

```
<? do_action('woo_custom_breadcrumb'); ?>
```

And works. My question is more than that. Is this the correct approach for something like this? I mean for anything over woocommerce, not just breadcrumb, for any pice, ratings, titles, buttons, sidebar, and so on.
What i´m thinking on is why woocommerce templates don´t come with more deep code. I mean, why there´s no such a single-content-loop.php template where you can just change the order of things, title, category, content, images, etc. in an easy way rather that hooking into functions?

Answer (score 0):

I think that is an acceptable way to call the breadcrumbs explicitly. Sometimes it is easier to call a specific function than remove everything around it!

As for changing the order of things and getting into advanced customization; there isn't a single file, but a number of files working together. Create a folder in your themes root called 'woocommerce'  and copy the following files for a safe override:

**woocommerce/woocommerce-hooks.php**:

Here are your hooks, including the ones you are overriding in your themes functions.php. Here is where you can experiment with removing and repositioning certain elements on your product page. Search for 'Sidebar' and you will see where the 'woocommerce_sidebar' action is added with the function it references in...

**woocommerce/woocommerce-template.php**:

Here are the functions used in template files to output content based on conditional statements. For instance, search for the 'Single Product' series and you can see which template files are used for which functions. For instance 'woocommerce_template_single_title' uses 'single-product/title.php' - if you copy over this folder and file you can make very specific edits to just the title section

Between these two files and their accompanying references (like title.php) I believe you can do the things you described. Let me know how it works out! I'm new to woocommerce too!

Comment: Turns out this might not be the best way to go about this. Check out https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/679